# ¿Cómo lograr que los cambios en JavaScript se apliquen automáticamente cuando son consultadas por los usuarios?

Tags: javascript

Si tengo una función llamada *hola_mundo* en un *JavaScript* y tiene varios días en producción ya varias personas han visitado la pagina que usa dicha función, evidentemente el usuario veía simplemente un "*hola mundo*", ahora bien cuando decido modificar dicha función para que ahora muestre como salida por ejemplo algo como "*hola mundo desde javascript probando cambios*" y entro a la pagina me sigue apareciendo el mensaje anterior "*hola mundo*".

Para que aplique los cambios debo dejar pegado varias veces las teclas <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> e incluso a veces no funciona, otras veces debo acceder al path directo del **`.js`** y darle <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> y a veces también viendo el código fuente de la pagina puedo acceder al **`.js`** y ver que no se actualiza los cambios hasta darle <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>.

¿Existe alguna forma de que esto no ocurra?, que pueda apenas hacer un cambio en mi código de *JavaScript* los cambios se reflejen puesto que a veces algunos usuarios me indican que tiene un error y es por que donde modifique los datos no se les ha actualizado y deben darle <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> varias veces.

Gracias.

Comment: Esto ocurre evidentemente porque el archivo antiguo se queda guardado en caché y podrían pasar días para que se actualice. Para solventar esto tú puedes agregar un número de versión del archivo y cambiar ese número cuando actualizas el archivo, así se cargará siempre el archivo con la última actualización. Sería simplemente agregar algo así al incluirlo: `elArchivo.js?ver=1.0`  supongamos que la caché se queda con ese archivo. Luego haces una modificación y quieres que la asuma, sólo tendrías que poner esto: `elArchivo.js?ver=1.1` y listo.

Comment: Aunque con HTML5 muchas cosas han cambiado. [Te recomiendo esta lectura](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Recursos_offline_en_firefox) si tu intención es programar aplicaciones web modernas.